# Switch tasks on active process to new process

Tags: process, nginx

What I'm going to explain is really about nginx processes, so maybe it can be done in nginx, or maybe its a Linux feature. In anyway, I hope it's possible.

I have an `ningx` process running, that looks like this:

```
root     19568  .....  nginx: master (old)
app      20769  .....  nginx: worker (old)
```

I then send a `USR2` signal to the master process: `kill -USR2 19568`

That gives me a new `master` and `worker` process:

```
root     19568  .....  nginx: master (old)
app      20769  .....  nginx: worker (old)
root     22716  .....  nginx: master (new)
app      22717  .....  nginx: worker (new)
```

So currently, the `old` processes are handeling all the data. Can I tell `nginx` or Ubuntu to swap those tasks to the new procceses?

---

### Why do I need this?

I know `nginx` has a `reload` command to dynamically reload its config. It can even update its own executable without any downtime.

But my nginx server uses a `TCP` module, so it is receiving data constantly. Because of that I cannot uses a `reload` or `HUP` command, because the worker processes are constantly busy. They cannot shut down.

Restarting nginx makes me loose all the client connections, and I really don't want that.

That's why I'm looking for a way to move the tasks that a certain process has to a new instance of that process.

Answer (score 0):

`Nginx` depends on worker processes being able to shutdown gracefully. Apparently it can start new requests with the newly applied configuration. But it does not continue already started requests.

To quote from http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html:

> Once the master process receives the signal to reload configuration, it checks the syntax validity of the new configuration file and tries to apply the configuration provided in it. If this is a success, the master process starts new worker processes and sends messages to old worker processes, requesting them to shut down. Otherwise, the master process rolls back the changes and continues to work with the old configuration. Old worker processes, receiving a command to shut down, stop accepting new connections and continue to service current requests until all such requests are serviced. After that, the old worker processes exit.

Though there apparently is a way to transfer sockets to another process in Linux - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997622/can-i-open-a-socket-and-pass-it-to-another-process-in-linux - it is still unlikely `nginx` would just 'pick up on that' and just start applying its given (new) configuration.

If the underlieing goal of this question is to apply changes to a running service without losing client connections in the future, you will probably have to ask another question.

That question may be about implementing some pause logic. Like saving state when asked to shutdown gracefully and restoring state (e.g. state associated with a certain session or request).